# How can I draw this graph in LaTex?

Tags: graphics

[image: I want to draw an image like this:]

I'm a beginner so I don't know how to do any of this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can start with something like this and add more styles as you wish.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} [thick]
\draw [<->] (0,4)node[left]{$y$}--(0,0)--(5,0)node[below]{$x$};
\draw [dashed] (0,2.5) -- (3.5,2.5)node[above right]{$z=(x,y)$} -- (3.5,0);
\draw [red] (0,0)--node[above=.5em]{\color{black}$|z|$}(3.5,2.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

Another, a wee bit more complex, possibility:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[> = Straight Barb]
\draw [<->] (0,4) node[below left]{$y$} |- (5,0) node[below left]{$x$};
\draw [dashed]  (3.5,  0) node[below] {$x_i$} -- 
                (3.5,2.5) coordinate[label=45:{$z=(x_i,y_j)$}] (v) -- 
                (0,  2.5) node[left] {$y_j$};
\path [draw=red, thick] (0,0) to ["$|z|$" sloped] (v);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: :-)))) hi very kind. Where you have taken from the original figure (x_i,y_j) and the single coordinates? ahahaah :-))))))))

Comment: @Sebastiano, this is missing in original question (to my opinion). In (good) od time in school we learned that some point in plane should designated on such a way  .